# PHP getting remote url image file size doesn't wait for content-length header to be set

Tags: php, image, file, image-processing, http-headers

I know this question has been asked millions of times, but please actually take the time to understand my problem before marking as duplicate or closing.

So I am using the following code. For some reason it gets all of the correct header information the first time I run the code EXCEPT for `content-length`. The second time I run the code it actually gets it correctly. I am retrieving the images from Facebook API if that changes anything.

```
function remote_filesize($url) {
  $data = get_headers($url, 1);
  if(isset($data['Content-Length'])) {
    return (int) $data['Content-Length'];
  }
  else {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Gotta love when you get downvoted with no explanation. Personally I think it should be required to provide a reason.

Anyway, this is still an issue, but in case anyone googling this needs a solution for getting the remote filesize, I would suggest using this awesome snippet from the PHP docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#114952

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a server caching issue.

So you may have to issue a full GET request instead of just a HEAD request.

Also, maybe check different casing -- 'content-length:' -- lowercase.